# Would socket.io receive data sent via websockets?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, iot, esp8266

I have this IoT device that I am trying to connect to the server via wifi to send real time data. The server uses socket.io with node.js, but the wifi module (esp8266) I am using only has a websocket package. Would a socket.io connection be able to receive data sent via websocket?

Comment: Have you looked at using MQTT or HTTP as a way to send data from the esp? Take a look at nodemcu also this has a lot of packages for the esp available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but it will be a bit of a kludge:

socket.io supports multiple transports, of which one of them is a websocket. You can connect using only the websocket, but you will need to implement the socket.io protocol.

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-protocol

If you are using a popular platform, there may be libraries available, i.e. for Arduino, there is:
https://github.com/billroy/socket.io-arduino-client